# bcp command to remove carraige return at the end of a text file

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does anyone know how i can remove a carraige return at the end of a text file???

I have created an SSIS package which exports the results to a text file.
However there is a carraige return at the end of each text file that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Powershell script for your case. Just provide the folder path(mentioned in the script) where all text files are placed. Copy the below code and save it as .ps1 and run with powershell.

```
function RemoveLastLine{
   param($folderpath)
   $filelist=Get-ChildItem $folderpath
   foreach($file in $filelist){
              $content=Get-Content $file
              $count=$content.count-2
        Set-Content $file  $a[0 .. $count]
    }

 }

 #provide folder path where all text files are placed
 $folderpath="<source folder path>"
 #calling the function
 RemoveLastLine $folderpath
```

Thanks